# What's a good choice of antenna tuners, if I add a 800 watt amp to my station

Tags: antenna-system

I am running a barefoot 100 watt radio for my HF operations now. Also using a MFJ tuner that's limit is 300 watts. I am putting on my wish list a 800 watt amp. So I know I will have to upgrade my tuner. Looking for suggestions on a new tuner to work with the new amp.  For HF I have 2 antennas to use, a multi band dipole stick, and a wire for multi band.  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, [questions asking for product recommendations are not allowed here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It's OK to ask questions about *what to look for in a product*, so if there's something you are unsure about besides exactly which model to buy, you can [edit] your question to focus on that.